# Use function to set value of field in BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, function, triggers

It's the first time I use a BEFORE INSERT trigger in Oracle.
I thought there would be no problem in setting one of the :new fields using a function, but apparently there is.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  
TRG_DESC_DOCUMENTO BEFORE INSERT ON DOTFILEPAT.DOCUMENTOS 
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE
VAR_SELECCION VARCHAR2(50);
VAR_CODIGO VARCHAR2(30);
VAR_VERIFICACION NUMBER;
BEGIN
VAR_SELECCION := :NEW.TIPO_DOCUMENTO;
VAR_CODIGO := :NEW.CODBARRAS;
--SELECT INSTR(:NEW.CODBARRAS,'F') INTO VAR_VERIFICACION FROM DUAL;
--IF(VAR_SELECCION = 'OFICIO' OR VAR_SELECCION = 'PROMOCION') THEN
:NEW.DESCRIPCION_DOCUMENTO := PATENTES.FN_NOMBRE_PROMO_OFICIOS(VAR_CODIGO,VAR_SELECCION);
--END IF;
END;
```

However it doesnt work because it only sets the :new.descripcion_documento value to null. However I tested setting directly that field (i. e. :new.descripcion_documento = 'SOMETHING') and that way it does work.

However I need to use the function to query the new value. This is the function:

```
create or replace FUNCTION FN_NOMBRE_PROMO_OFICIOS(CODIGO IN VARCHAR2,TIPO_DOCUM IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS 
VAR_SALIDA VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  IF(TIPO_DOCUM = 'PROMOCION') THEN
  BEGIN
    SELECT LISTAGG(TAUX.DES_TIPO,' | ' ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY TAUX.DES_TIPO) INTO VAR_SALIDA FROM TIPO_PROMOCION TAUX INNER JOIN 
    PROMOCION_TIPO P ON P.TIP_PROMOCION = TAUX.TIP_PROMOCION INNER JOIN PROMOCION PAUX ON PAUX.COD_OFICINA = P.COD_OFICINA
    AND PAUX.TIP_LIBRO = P.TIP_LIBRO AND PAUX.SER_DOCUM = P.SER_DOCUM AND PAUX.NUM_DOCUM = P.NUM_DOCUM INNER JOIN DOTFILEPAT.DOCUMENTOS D ON D.CODBARRAS =
    PAUX.COD_OFICINA||'/'||PAUX.TIP_LIBRO||'/'||PAUX.SER_DOCUM||'/'||LPAD(PAUX.NUM_DOCUM,6,0)
    WHERE UPPER(D.TIPO_DOCUMENTO) ='PROMOCION' AND D.CODBARRAS = CODIGO;
  END;
  ELSIF(TIPO_DOCUM = 'OFICIO') THEN
  BEGIN 
  SELECT T.DES_OFICIO INTO VAR_SALIDA FROM TIPO_OFICIO T INNER JOIN OFICIO O ON O.TIP_OFICIO = T.TIP_OFICIO INNER JOIN DOTFILEPAT.DOCUMENTOS D ON D.CODBARRAS = 
O.COD_OFICINA_OFICIO||'/'||O.SER_OFICIO||'/'||O.NUM_OFICIO WHERE UPPER(D.TIPO_DOCUMENTO) ='OFICIO' AND D.CODBARRAS = CODIGO;
  END;

END IF;
  RETURN VAR_SALIDA;
  EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN

    IF(TIPO_DOCUM = 'PROMOCION') THEN
        SELECT TAUX.DES_TIPO INTO VAR_SALIDA FROM TIPO_PROMOCION TAUX INNER JOIN 
        PROMOCION_TIPO P ON P.TIP_PROMOCION = TAUX.TIP_PROMOCION INNER JOIN PROMOCION PAUX ON PAUX.COD_OFICINA = P.COD_OFICINA
        AND PAUX.TIP_LIBRO = P.TIP_LIBRO AND PAUX.SER_DOCUM = P.SER_DOCUM AND PAUX.NUM_DOCUM = P.NUM_DOCUM INNER JOIN DOTFILEPAT.DOCUMENTOS D ON D.CODBARRAS =
        PAUX.COD_OFICINA||'/'||PAUX.TIP_LIBRO||'/'||PAUX.SER_DOCUM||'/'||LPAD(PAUX.NUM_DOCUM,6,0)
        WHERE UPPER(D.TIPO_DOCUMENTO) ='PROMOCION' AND D.CODBARRAS = CODIGO AND P.IND_PRIMERO = 'S';
        RETURN VAR_SALIDA;
        ELSE RETURN NULL;
    END IF;
   
END FN_NOMBRE_PROMO_OFICIOS;
```

Any idea why running the function is not working in the trigger ?

UPDATE: I followed Brian Dellinger suggestion and edited my code like this:

```
create or replace TRIGGER  
DOTFILEPAT.TRG_DESC_DOCUMENTO FOR UPDATE OR INSERT ON DOTFILEPAT.DOCUMENTOS 
COMPOUND TRIGGER
TYPE R_DOCUMENTOS IS RECORD(
CODIGOBARRAS DOCUMENTOS.CODBARRAS%TYPE,
DESC_DOCUM DOCUMENTOS.DESCRIPCION_DOCUMENTO%TYPE
);
TYPE T_DOCUMENTOS IS TABLE OF R_DOCUMENTOS
INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
REGISTRO_DOCUM T_DOCUMENTOS;

AFTER EACH ROW IS
BEGIN
REGISTRO_DOCUM(REGISTRO_DOCUM.COUNT +1).CODIGOBARRAS := :NEW.CODBARRAS;
REGISTRO_DOCUM(REGISTRO_DOCUM.COUNT +1).DESC_DOCUM := PATENTES.FN_NOMBRE_PROMO_OFICIOS(:NEW.CODBARRAS,:NEW.TIPO_DOCUMENTO);
END AFTER EACH ROW;

AFTER STATEMENT IS
BEGIN
--SELECT INSTR(:NEW.CODBARRAS,'F') INTO VAR_VERIFICACION FROM DUAL;
FOR INDX IN 1.. REGISTRO_DOCUM.COUNT
LOOP
UPDATE DOTFILEPAT.DOCUMENTOS SET DESCRIPCION_DOCUMENTO = REGISTRO_DOCUM(INDX).CODIGOBARRAS WHERE CODBARRAS = REGISTRO_DOCUM(INDX).CODIGOBARRAS;
END LOOP;
END AFTER STATEMENT;
END;
```

However I don't seem to have created the trigger correctly cause now I get a

> ORA-04091: la tabla DOTFILEPAT.DOCUMENTOS está mutando, puede que el disparador/la función no puedan verla

But the compound trigger seems to be the way, any comments on how to make a compound trigger work?

I also edited the definition of the trigger including the OF COLUMN statement:

```
DOTFILEPAT.TRG_DESC_DOCUMENTO FOR INSERT OR UPDATE OF DESCRIPCION_DOCUMENTO ON DOTFILEPAT.DOCUMENTOS
```

But still the problem isn't solved.

UPDATE: Thank you for your attention, as Pugzly asked, I upload the CREATE TABLE script and a minimal DataSet.

Here are the links to them:
[Dataset](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IqNxh-3uI-pUalaE0xHCPktTKclXcRYI/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=108295574298151881664&rtpof=true&sd=true)
[CREATE TABLE script](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10ZNSM_ypf6G-iem6TCANqD8JzkPlU9KL/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I have also tested the funcion and it does return a value that is not null for the cases I have tested, but apparently it's running too slow for the trigger to work

Comment: you are doing a before trigger on Dotfilepat.documentos but your function is referencing that table.  my guess is instead of a before trigger you are going to need to use a compound trigger.  https://www.oracletutorial.com/plsql-tutorial/mutating-table-error-in-oracle/

Comment: @BryanDellinger I tried to follow your suggestion

Comment: It would probably help if you can supply a minimal test CASE, which includes a create table statement, sample data and a minimal function. Ie just give the minimal code that will show the problem

Comment: @Pugzly I uploaded the script and dataset. Thanks

Comment: @Geraldo just give me something simple like this. Provide a simple insert statement that will fire the trigger so we can see where the problem is in your code.  CREATE TABLE employees (employee_id, first_name, last_name, department_id, sal) AS
SELECT 1, 'Alice', 'Abbot', 1, 100000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Beryl', 'Baron', 1, 50000 FROM DUAL;